# jQuery how two separated UL behave like one

Tags: jquery, if-statement, removeclass

i am stuck with my script and I hope I can explain my problem, because its quite complicated to explain. My navigation has 2 separated < ul > with each 3 levels. The 1st level on both UL's are displayed and the other 2 nested on each are hidden. If I click a Link with a nested UL this will slide from right to left and the level 1 UL gets a class name "inactive" like this < ul class="inactive" > otherwise the Link will opened. That would be the same thing with the 2nd level.

This works fine but only for the same UL tree. The 2 separated UL should behave like one.
To understand my problem please have a look at this link: http://jsfiddle.net/VZTR9/

The markup looks like this

```
<nav id="mobile-nav">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" title="Nav">(ul 1) Link</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" title="Sub Nav">(ul 1) Link 2</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" title="Sub Nav 2">(ul 1) Link 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" title="Sub Nav 2">(ul 1) Link 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" title="Sub Nav">(ul 1) Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" title="Sub Nav">(ul 1) Link 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" title="Nav">(ul 1) Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="Nav">(ul 1) Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="Nav">(ul 1) Link</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="second">
    <li><a href="#" title="Nav">(ul 2) Link</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" title="Sub Nav">(ul 2) Link 2</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" title="Sub Nav 2">(ul 2) Link 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" title="Sub Nav 2">(ul 2) Link 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" title="Sub Nav">(ul 2) Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" title="Sub Nav">(ul 2) Link 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" title="Nav">(ul 2) Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="Nav">(ul 2) Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="Nav">(ul 2) Link</a></li>
</ul></nav>
```

And the script

```
$('#mobile-nav').on('click', 'a', function(){

var navWidth    = jQuery('#mobile-nav').width();
var speed       = 200;

if( jQuery(this).closest('ul').hasClass('inactive') ){
    //alert("has inactive class");

    jQuery(this).closest('ul').find('ul').animate({
        right: '-' + navWidth,
        opacity: "hide"
    }, speed);

    jQuery(this).closest('ul').removeClass('inactive');
    jQuery(this).closest('ul').find('ul').removeClass('inactive');
    return false;

} else {
    //alert("no inactive class");

    if( ( jQuery(this).parent().has('ul').length > 0 ) && ( !jQuery(this).parent().find('ul').is(':visible') ) ) {
        //alert("has ul and is visible");

        jQuery(this).closest('ul').addClass('inactive');
        jQuery(this).next('ul').animate({
            right: "0px",
            opacity: "show"
        }, speed);

        return false;
    } else {
        alert("open Link");
        return false;
    }
}});
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It's because your jQuery selector is too high.  `.find()` gets all children that match the selector.  You need to be more specific in how you select your `ul`s